# Writing a wav file using sounddevice and numpy in python3

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, audio

I would like to record a tone with sounddevice i created numpy and write it into a wav file. here is the  code:

```
import numpy 
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import sys

duration = 3
amplitude = 0.3
sampling_frequency = 44100

time = numpy.arange(int(numpy.ceil(duration * sampling_frequency))) /   sampling_frequency

frequency1 = 500
tone1 = amplitude * numpy.sin(2* numpy.pi * frequency1 * time)

frequency2 = 700
tone2 = amplitude * numpy.sin(2* numpy.pi * frequency1 * time)
frequency3 = 1500
tone3 = amplitude * numpy.sin(3* numpy.pi * frequency1 * time)
frequency4 = 400
tone4 = amplitude * numpy.sin(4* numpy.pi * frequency1 * time)

result = tone1
result2 = tone2
result3 = tone3
result4 = tone4

sd.play(result + result2 + result3 + result4, sampling_frequency)

filename = 'output.wav'

mydata = sd.rec(int(result + result2 + result3 + result4),sampling_frequency,channels=2, blocking=True)
sf.write(filename, mydata, sampling_frequency)
```

I get this error: only length-1 arrays can be converted to Python scalars
What's wrong with the code? I'm a newbie with python

Comment: It would be helpful if you added the full error message, as it specifies which line yields the error.

Answer (score 2):

Your second-to-last line is

```
mydata = sd.rec(int(result + result2 + result3 + result4),sampling_frequency,channels=2, blocking=True)
```

Where you try to cast the sum of the `result1` etc variables to an integer. However, they are actually `numpy` arrays, since `time` is an array. You cannot convert an array into a single integer, since it has multiple values. I'm not sure why you are trying to do that, you probably just want to remove the `int()`, and change it to

```
mydata = sd.rec(result + result2 + result3 + result4, sampling_frequency, channels=2, blocking=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

`sd.rec()` is used to record sound from a sound device and output an array. It expects an integer of how long the recording should be. That is why it was throwing `"TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer"`.
https://python-sounddevice.readthedocs.io/en/0.3.7/#recording

You don't have to record the data, because you already have the data (your result variables). So you should just replace

```
mydata = sd.rec(int(result + result2 + result3 + result4),sampling_frequency,channels=2, blocking=True)
```

with

```
mydata = result + result2 + result3 + result4
```

Answer (score 0):

Fyi, your "tone" formulas all use "frequency1" in them, instead of 1, 2, 3, & 4.
This code works for me, tho I wasn't sure if you wanted to overlap the tones, or play them in sequence, so I did both:

```
import numpy as np
import sounddevice as sd
import soundfile as sf
import sys

duration = 3
amplitude = 0.3
sampling_frequency = 44100

frequency1 = 500
frequency2 = 700
frequency3 = 1500
frequency4 = 400

time = np.arange(int(np.ceil(duration * sampling_frequency))) / sampling_frequency

tone1 = amplitude * np.sin(2* np.pi * frequency1 * time)
tone2 = amplitude * np.sin(2* np.pi * frequency2 * time)
tone3 = amplitude * np.sin(3* np.pi * frequency3 * time)
tone4 = amplitude * np.sin(4* np.pi * frequency4 * time)

result = tone1 + tone2 + tone3 + tone4

# overlaps the tones
sd.play(result, sampling_frequency)
sd.wait()
sf.write('tone.wav', result, sampling_frequency)

sequence = np.append(tone1, [tone2, tone3, tone4])

# plays each tone in sequence
sd.play(sequence, sampling_frequency)
sd.wait()
sf.write('sequence.wav', sequence, sampling_frequency)
```